# Is $\mathbb{Z}$ universally definable in any number fields other than $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, lo.logic, algebraic-number-theory, model-theory, definability

In 2009, Jochen Koenigsmann [showed](https://annals.math.princeton.edu/wp-content/uploads/Koenigsmann.pdf) that $\mathbb{Z}$ is universally definable in the field $\mathbb{Q}$.  My question is, are there any other number fields in which $\mathbb{Z}$ is universally definable?

Or failing that, what is the lowest complexity definition of $\mathbb{Z}$ known for a number field other than $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Of course there are the results of Jennifer Park generalizing Koenigsmann's result to number fields, but in the sense of giving a universal definition of the ring of integers of $K$ in $K$... Combining that with the results of Denef and others one can at least get an $\exists\forall$-definition of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $K$ for many $K$.

Comment: @ArnoFehm I think this should be an answer.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: Ok, will do so, but I'm not sure that one doesn't know an $\forall$-definition at least in some cases.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Koenigsmann's result was generlized by [Jennifer Park](https://arxiv.org/abs/1202.6371) to number fields, giving a universal definition of the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ in $K$. Then there is a series of results proving that $\mathbb{Z}$ is existentially definable in $\mathcal{O}_K$ for certain $K$, starting I think with results by [Jan Denef](https://doi.org/10.2307/1998133) (totally real number fields, or quadratic extension of a totally real field). Combining the two, one gets an $\exists\forall$-definition of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $K$ at least for these number fields.

It is possible though that one also has an $\forall$-definition of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $K$ for some number fields $K\neq\mathbb{Q}$, but I don't remember right now.